# Calculate $\lim _{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_0^{\pi} \sin (x+\frac{x^{2019}}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis

> Calculate $\lim _{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_0^{\pi} \sin (x+\frac{x^{2019}}{n})$

I tried to find some $f(x), g(x)$ such that: $$\int_0^{\pi} f(x) \le \int_0^{\pi} \sin (x+\frac{x^{2019}}{n}) \le \int_0^{\pi} g(x)$$ $$\int_0^{\pi} f(x) \rightarrow 2$$
$$\int_0^{\pi} g(x) \rightarrow 2$$
However my only idea is $$\sin (x+\frac{x^{2019}}{n}) \le x+\frac{x^{2019}}{n}$$ but it is not helpfull for me.
 Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 5):

$\sin$ is continuous and bounded by $1$ in absolute value. By DCT the limit is $\int_0^{\pi} \sin\, x dx$. Can you calculate this integral?.